# Objective-C - drawing a horizontal line through the middle of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrectmake

I'm trying to draw a horizontal line through the middle of the screen of an app that has a navigation bar. Here's my current code to do so:

```
CGFloat screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
CGFloat navigationBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
CGFloat lineThickness = 3;

UIView *horizontalLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (screenHeight - navigationBarHeight) / 2, screenWidth, lineThickness)];
[self.view addSubview:horizontalLine];
```

I used a very similar calculation to draw a vertical line - and that worked just fine. But, the issue is, regardless of device, this horizontal line ends up too low on the screen by roughly 10 pixels. Is there an offset I may be missing? Something to do with the navigation bar perhaps?

Comment: You mean the status bar height?

Comment: I mean the navigation bar that comes from using a navigation controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i did it like this first .. but it wasnt centered.  but it SHOULD BE! :)
under this i changed it to add a view to wrap it all and that seemed to "work"
you can try either or, or a combination of some of the elements and see how that goes.

```
UIView *horizontalLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

[self.view addSubview:horizontalLine];

[horizontalLine setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];

horizontalLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

id topGuide = self.topLayoutGuide;
id bottomGuide = self.bottomLayoutGuide;

NSDictionary * viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(horizontalLine, topGuide, bottomGuide);

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[horizontalLine]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[topGuide][horizontalLine(==3)][bottomGuide]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];


[self.view addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:horizontalLine
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:self.view
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];
```

"wrapped" approach.  it's a bit messy but it might give you some ideas of things to try

```
UIView * wrapper = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

UIView *horizontalLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

[wrapper setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];
[horizontalLine setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];

[self.view addSubview:wrapper];
[wrapper addSubview:horizontalLine];

horizontalLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

id topGuide = self.topLayoutGuide;
id bottomGuide = self.bottomLayoutGuide;

NSDictionary * viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(horizontalLine, topGuide, bottomGuide, wrapper);

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[wrapper]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[topGuide][wrapper][bottomGuide]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];

[wrapper addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[horizontalLine]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];

[wrapper addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(>=1)-[horizontalLine(==3)]-(>=1)-|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];

[wrapper addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:horizontalLine
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:wrapper
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do like @myte's solution. If I am doing the same feature, I will use `NSLayoutConstraint` as well. However, to answer your question directly, what you are missing is the status bar. The status bar is normally 20 pixels in height. When you divide that by 2, you get 10 pixels exactly.

```
CGFloat screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
CGFloat navigationBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
CGFloat lineThickness = 3;

// This is what you are missing
CGFloat statusBarHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;

UIView *horizontalLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (screenHeight - navigationBarHeight - statusBarHeight) / 2, screenWidth, lineThickness)];
[self.view addSubview:horizontalLine];
```

P.S.: You mentioned that the problem is "regardless of device", however, if you try it on iPhone 4S in landscape mode, it may just be centred every well because the status bar is hidden :P ([link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6542093?start=0&tstart=0)).